# compare one value with four tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare ssn with four tables to find any unmatched ssn. i need assistance with sql query. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: More info please. What did you try so far? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Any code to put here so we can take a look at whatever you have tried already?

Comment: Look at left join and where IS NULL ... that's fast way of doing this

Comment: My apologies, this was my first post. but i have tried

Comment: select ssn from table 1
intersect 
select ssn from table 2
intersect
select ssn from table 3
intersect 
select ssn from table 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided, the basic concept would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    ssn NOT IN (
                SELECT ssn
                FROM ssnTable1
                )
    AND 
    ssn NOT IN (
                SELECT ssn
                FROM ssnTable2
                )
    AND 
    ssn NOT IN (
                SELECT ssn
                FROM ssnTable3
                )
    AND 
    ssn NOT IN (
                SELECT ssn
                FROM ssnTable4
                )
```

If the ssn should exist in all four tables at once, then replace the above ANDs with ORs.

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for ^^^ thank you MORGB :)